# Do airliners perform a dive maneuver to reduce altitude

Tags: airliner, boeing-747, airbus-a380, rudder, horizontal-stabilizer

DO airliners, jumbos included, like the Airbus A380 and Boeing 747 routinely perform dive (nose down) maneuvers to descend or do they rather reduce speed and descend with the nose up? If not, why not?

Comment: Dives are done in emergency. Why dive if you can smoothly and comfortably descend along a slope? (But your comment about nose up is a bit puzzling, do you define "diving" as anything with a nose down?)

Comment: Yes that is what I define diving

Comment: Then just a terminology note: "diving" usually refers to a rapid descent, otherwise you simply speak of a descent.

Comment: Do they perform dives to reduce altitude? Yes, in certain emergency situations. Is this a normal procedure? Not unless it's one of those emergency situations.

Comment: The described procedure resembles the _combat approach_, which can be done by military cargo planes to remain as long as possible out of the range of small arms.